# mdadm trying to resync/rebuild array automatically

Tags: server, raid, mdadm

Previously I had setup a ubuntu server using mdadm with 4x 2TB drives. One of my drives died and since this was my backups of my data on different servers I didn't care about losing it.

Since then, I've purchased a replacement drive and some new server hardware. I completely reinstalled ubuntu on my SSD, then I deleted the partition table and volumes on all 4 of the 2TB drives. Then I went to create a brand new array but when I do, it immediately says degraded and it is trying to resync my new drive with the old array I had setup.

How do I just get it to create a new array so I can format the entire array and create a new empty volume?

Note: I was doing this in the Ubuntu desktop in the unity GUI with the disk utility.

Since then I've changed over to a full headless server install, but I still want to create this array so it doesn't try to resync the replacement disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have dissembled/stopped the old array and created a new one with mdadm, right? In that case the superblocks of the old array on all drives should have been overwritten, the old array is no more. But, now you are wondering why you see something like following in /proc/mdstat, right?

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 loop6[6] loop5[4] loop4[3] loop3[2] loop2[1] loop1[0]
      511680 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/5] [UUUUU_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  2.0% (2176/102336) finish=0.7min speed=2176K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

This is just fine for [initial array creation](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Initial_Array_Creation).

Comment: Thanks, actually you got me on the right track. All I had to do was zero the superblock on all the devices.